# Functions aren't printing messages but program completely runs?

Tags: python, function, class, oop

Hello I am currently working on updating a project from when I first was learning to code. With that being said I am starting to implement classes withing the program when I have run into a bit of a Issue not like a physical Python Error but my Class Functions just don't seem to perform properly.

WebSite.py

> ```
> class WebSite:
>   def __init__(self, url, id):
>       self.__url = url
>       self.__id = id
>       
>   def getURL(self):
>       return self.__url
>       
>   def getId(self):
>       return self.__id
> ```

GunSite.py

```
> class GunSite(WebSite):

      def __init__(self, url):

    self.__url = url

    self.__id = {

        'shotgun' : 'shotguns',

        'handgun' : 'handguns',

            'rifle' :  'rifles',

        'tactical' : 'tactical'

         }

        

         self.__lcount = 0

         self.__gun_listings = []
         
         super().__init__(self.__url, self.__id)

        

    def setKeyValue(self, key, value):

        self.__id[key] = value

        

    def getKeys(self):

        for id in self.__get():

            print(id)

    def __get(self):

            for id in self.__id:

                yield self.__id[id]

    

    def getKey(self, key):

        return self.__id[key]

        

    def __addListing(self, listing):

        self.__gun_listings.append(listing)

        print(f"Added New Listing {self.__gun_listings(self.__lcount)} to Listings List")

        self.__lcount = self.__lcount + 1


def gatherListings(self, url):

        html_url = requests.get(url).text

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_url, "lxml")

        listings = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-6 col-md-4 outer-tiles product-impression')

        

        for listing in listings:

            print("Gathering Listing name, price, etc..")

            name = listing.find('span', class_='first-line d-lg-none').text

            price = listing.find('span', class_='sales').text

            desc = listing.find('div', class_='pdp-link')

            desc_url = desc.a['href']

            print("Gathered Listing Data!")

            

            print("Creating new GunListing Object...")

            gun_listing = GunListing(name, price, desc, desc_url)

            print("Object Created successfully!")

            print("Adding Listing Object to List of Listings...")

            

            self.__addListing(gun_listing)

            print("Finished Successfully!

def getListings(self):
            print("Displaying Data for all Listings")
            
            for glisting in self.__gun_listings:
                name = glisting.getName()
                price = glisting.getPrice()
                desc = glisting.getDesc()
                desc_url = glisting.getDescURL()
                
                print(f"-----------------------------------------------------------")
                print(f"Listing Name: {name}")
                print(f"Listing Price: {price}")
                print(f"Desc: {desc}")
                print(f"For more info about this handgun, Visit {desc_url}")
                print(f"-----------------------------------------------------------")
```

Listing.py

```
class Listing:

    def __inti__(self, name, price, desc, desc_url):

        self.__name = name

        self.__price = price

        self.__desc = desc

        self.__desc_url = desc_url

    



    def getName(self):

        return self.__name

    

    def getPrice(self):

        return self.__price

        

    def getDesc(self):

        return self.__desc

        

    def getDescURL(self):

        return self.__desc_url
```

GunListing.py

```
from Listing import Listing

class GunListing(Listing):

    def __init__(self, name, price, desc, desc_url):

        self.__name = name

        self.__price = price

        self.__desc = desc

        self.__desc_url = desc_url

        super().__init__(self.__name, self.__price, self.__desc, self.__desc_url)
```

I expected the program to run through and complete everything in every function that I have created and called. But it isn't running anything in my functions just the code on the outside of the functions.

CODE IM RUNNING

> 

```
gun_site = GunSite('https://www.cheaperthandirt.com/')

print(f"Gathering Listings for Website {gun_site.getURL()}")

gun_site.gatherListings(gun_site.getURL() + gun_site.getKey('shotgun') + '/')

print(f"Finished Successfully Gathering Listings for {gun_site.getURL()}")

print(f"Collecting All of the Listings from {gun_site.getURL()}")

gun_site.getListings()

print(f"Successfully Collected and Displayed Listings form {gun_site.getURL()}")
```

[image: Console / Program Runs everything except functions??]

Comment: You're using `requests` to fetch the website, which cannot process javascript.  You'll need to use some other method of fetching the website.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but thank you for a Answer. So with the fact that my code is not processing javascript would I use a module like js2py or is this something I could obtain without it.

Comment: You'll need to use some other tool that acts more like a full browser, for example selenium.